# android: How check image drawable?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Hi I'm using this code for checking current image:

```
public void onToggle(View view){
    ImageView imageFav = (ImageView) view;
    if (imageFav.getResources().equals(R.drawable.fave_icon_1)) {
        dataSource.addToFavorite(idiom);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fave_icon_2);

    }else if(imageFav.getResources().equals(R.drawable.fave_icon_2)){
        dataSource.deleteFromFavorite(idiom);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fave_icon_1);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_fav_icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:onClick="onToggle"
      android:src="@drawable/fave_icon_1" />
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a generic way for checking current drawable.
Any idea?

Comment: Use setTag() and getTag instead. You can define the initial value in XML and change it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are comparing the ImageView with a drawable id and, of course, the comparison will give never true as result. What you could is to have two different images view and toggle the visibility of the two, checking the id of the one you click on

Answer (score 1):

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.id.icon).toString().equals(R.drawable.icon)
```

it have worked for me i hope it may solve your problem